# How do you digitally sign an Office.js Add-in?

Tags: office-js, digital-signature, add-in

We've noticed that when our office.js add-in is added to MSWord that some clients are experiencing the following macro warning:

"The function you are attempting to run contains macros or content that requires macro language support.  When this software was installed, you (or your administrator) chose not to install support for macros or controls".

This warning appears every time a document opens.  Or worse, if a document compare operation is actioned (i.e. MSWord's native compare functionality) the warning is shown about 20 times as it attempts to open each document (original and revised) in order to execute the compare operation.

For some clients the macro warning settings are unavailable due to their strict security policy, preventing them from disabling this notification.

Presumably we need to digitally sign our Office.js add-in/website somehow to suppress these notifications without having to change the policy setting.  Are there any articles describing how to digitially sign an Office.js add-in/website?

Comment: This is very strange. I recommend that you raise this as an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=) repo.

Comment: I have a working native compare function in MSWord.  Then when I create this helloWorld application and run it the native compare starts breaking in the same way - throwing up multiple macro warnings  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-react

The warnings only occur on my corporate laptop.  If I repeat the same test on a previous employers laptop the warnings are not shown